# Pass Shopping Basket to Backend

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm making a web application (back-end with laravel , front-end with AngularJS).
What way is more proper to pass the shopping basket to back-end.
Should I put that in a input , next to submit button , inside a form?

Comment: Serialize form with formData (check IE here), and send it with ajax request. That's what I do, but I am not angular dev so you may have other choices

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you need to pass information about which product user want to buy. I don't know your routing but probably you've got ID of product in URL. If so you can get it by `$routeParams` in controller and assign it to some variable.

Next if you already have rest API endpoint finished you need to call it with `$http`. Remember that controllers shouldn't do too much so you probably should create a service which will make this `$http` call, inject it into controller and execute. It would look like

```
myServiceName.doHttpCall(productID);
```

Comment: Actually I use angular to implement a shopping basket , I store informations in a object and by pressing finish button , it should be sent to back-end